# The MOOC tag, should it stay or should it go?

Tags: discussion, tags

Today I've seen this tag:

[mooc](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mooc)

Which seems very narrow scoped. I think it should go.

Comment: Narrow-scoped is not necessarily a problem with a tag. If people would naturally say “I'm looking for a mooc”, then it's fine as a tag name. What this tag needs is a definition, and possibly a better (unabbreviated) name: what the hell is a mooc?

Comment: As the tag wiki says its an online course format. I wouldn't keep "online course" as a tag on this site either as it is on specific form of video stream. The name is about content not format. "Video Streaming Service" if sufficiently used could be a tag. But mooc?. I collect my thoughts and post an answer to it containing the reasons I think it should go together with comparison to other tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would agree that [mooc](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mooc) should go but that is more due to the fact that a MOOC is a service as opposed a piece of software.

Perhaps eliminate [mooc](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mooc) and add a  [educational-software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/educational-software) or file it under [collaboration](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collaboration)